# Accessing virtual host by ip

Tags: php, apache, paypal, virtualhost, paypal-ipn

I have a Virtual Host in my machine with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  ServerName codigos
  DocumentRoot /home/code/codigos/app/webroot
  SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory /home/code/codigos/app/webroot > 
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Ok, that works nice when I type this in my browser: `codigos/some_path` and `127.0.0.1/some_path`
But now I'm working with PayPal and I need a url for the IPN. I know that I cant' put `localhost` in the url, so I suppose that it would be something like this: `my.dynamic.ip/some_path/ipn.php` ... and thats my problem, I don't know how to configure my apache file to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: have you got a public ip?

Comment: You're basically going to replace the 127.0.0.1 with your public IP and put my.dynamic.ip as the `ServerName`. Elsewhere in the config you need to set Apache to listen on your public IP. If you need https, that will take some additional configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Register at http://www.noip.com/ (or any other dynamic dns site)
2. Set up their software so that you was possible to `ping blabla.noip.com` host (or whatever host you've got after the registration and setting up process) and see it resolves to your ip (you can check it with `my ip` in google)
3. After that put the given hostname `blabla.noip.com` to the `ServerName` or (better) `ServerAlias` directive

After that you'll be able to access to your virtual host from outside (assuming your firewall doesn't reject connections and you have white IP address)